# MPICH installation

Tags: software-installation, mpi

I searching on internet how to download the MPICH in my laptop, and something is going wrong... I don't know what is happening. I am using ubuntu 18.04. Someone know any good installation video, or doc to use and download it? I am trying to do the installation since 3 days and I can't... Sorry for the silly question

Comment: Are you sure you can't use the version that is provided by the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: if I write '''mpiexec --version''' tells me: mpiexec(OpenRTE) 2.1.1. But when I try to run a basic program like hello world, nothing happend...

Answer (score 16):

1. Install mpich from the default Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt install mpich
```

2. Copy the below hello world C code into a new file named mpi_hello_world.c and save.

```c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
           processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

3. Change directories to the directory which contains mpi_hello_world.c, then compile and run the code with the following commands.

```
mpicc mpi_hello_world.c -o hello-world  
mpirun -np 5 ./hello-world
```

Comment: I get:```[-ideapad-3-15iil05:562228] *** Process received signal ***
[-ideapad-3-15iil05:562228] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[-ideapad-3-15iil05:562228] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[-ideapad-3-15iil05:562228] Failing at address: (nil)
[-ideapad-3-15iil05:562228] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f73e562d520]
[-ideapad-3-15iil05:562228] *** End of error message ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)```